# ValueError at /admin/ in Django

Tags: django, openldap, python-ldap

Thanks for looking into this. I'm very new to Django and LDAP Config....so any help is greatly appreciated!

ActivePython 2.6, Django-1.2.7, openldap-2.4.23, python-ldap

So i have the Django installed. I'm trying to configure LDAP to it by following this instruction http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/901/.

After making making changes as described in the above document, and when i run 'python manage.py runserver' I'm gettting this error. Any idea why this is happening? Been looking at this for about a week and no idea how to get this fixed.

```
Error:
ValueError at /admin/

option error

Request Method:     POST 
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin/ 
Django Version:     1.2.7
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

option error

Exception Location:     /apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/functions.py in _ldap_function_call, line 63
Python Executable:  /apps/essw/python/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.7
Python Path:    ['/apps/essw/mysite', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.6.egg', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Markdown-2.2.0-py2.6.egg', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/html5lib-0.95-py2.6.egg', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python26.zip', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info']
Server time:    Wed, 25 Jul 2012 09:06:41 -0500
```

@ChrisPratt Thanks for the reply Chris! See if this is helpful

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://x.x.x.x:8080/admin/
Django Version: 1.2.7
Python Version: 2.6.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in     get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args,        **callback_kwargs)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in     wrapper
  208.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in     _wrapped_view
  76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"     in _wrapped_view_func
  78.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in     inner
  190.                 return self.login(request)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"     in _wrapped_view_func
  78.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in     login
  323.         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py"     in authenticate
  52.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/apps/essw/mysite/django_auth_ldap/backend.py" in authenticate
  824.          ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE,settings.AD_CERT_FILE)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.6-linux-    x86_64.egg/ldap/functions.py" in set_option
  132.   return _ldap_function_call(None,_ldap.set_option,option,invalue)
File "/apps/essw/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.6-linux-    x86_64.egg/ldap/functions.py" in _ldap_function_call
  63.       result = func(*args,**kwargs)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/
Exception Value: option error
```

Comment: Post the *full* stack trace. While what you gave us is more verbose than "I got a ValueError exception", it still doesn't give us any useful information to diagnose it.

Comment: There's something wrong with this line in your custom authentication backend: `ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE,settings.AD_CERT_FILE)` . Check the syntax in documentation for that library, and also make sure that the values you're passing are of the proper types.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Hi Chris! That's exactly where the error is happening. If i comment out ldap.set_option(), the site would work. I cannot seem to find why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.